# StackScrollView subviews not being removed

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I am using the [StackScrollView iOS library](https://github.com/raweng/StackScrollView) in my iPad app. My master view initially consists of a table. When the user selects a cell, a View Controller is created and added to the stack as follows:

```
DualChartViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DualChartPageVC"];
[vc setObj:newObj];
[((MasteriPadViewController *)[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].mainVC).stackScrollViewController addViewInSlider:vc invokeByController:self isStackStartView:FALSE];
```

This works as expected the first time a user selects a cell; however, the DualChart views are never removed, so in subsequent selections they simply pile up on top of each other (forcing the user to swipe each of them away multiple times).

How should I de-allocate these views properly so that there are never more than two subviews added to my StackScrollViewController (the table and the DualChartViewController)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

Although my StackViewController object was removing my view controller from it's viewControllersStack array, it for some reason wasn't removing it from slideViews' subviews. I modified my didSelectCell method so that if it wasn't the first selection made, I would remove the last object from slideViews' subviews before adding the new view. Now it works perfectly!

Comment: [[[slideViews subviews] lastObject] removeFromSuperview];

Comment: Thanks it works but I am using viewForHeaderInSection and every time I select a cell, this code will remove one label from the table view header. Weird but it is happening. any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I have fixed it by setting tags to the UILabels as shown:     for (UIView *subView in [[[slideViews subviews] lastObject] subviews])
    {
        if (subView.tag != 111) // &&![subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]
            [subView removeFromSuperview];
    }